# Windows Inkscape drawing save vs macOS Inkscape drawing save

Tags: inkscape, document-setup

I've used for quite some time the Inkscape application on Windows. When I used to save one of my drawings, automatically it did not save the entire document page as an SVG including the white contours, but the drawing's edges only, which was so useful.

Now I've recently switched to macOS and this automatic behavior doesn't happen. I managed to go to File -> Document Properties... -> Resize to content, but this: 1) is a "manual" operation 2) it doesn't work properly, some whitespaces are left and I don't know why. Someone can help?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It sounds like you talking about using the Export feature rather than saving, perhaps trying [to export a selection](https://imgur.com/ud8pF45). Is that correct? You will need to provide more information such as showing your settings. Could you take a screenshot, and also show what the problem is? If you think something is really not working as it should, then it could potentially be a bug. If so, then you should [report it to the Inkscape developers](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/). Not much we can do here if it's a bug.